# How do you track versions in Bugzilla?

Tags: versioning, bugzilla

We are in the process of migrating our bug tracking to Bugzilla from a really old version of track and I am running out of Advil.

We have a legacy application that has been around for a long time.  Mix in the fact that our versioning management has been through a few iterations it generated a lot of different versions in the wild.  To make matters worse, because of contractual limitations it is not always possible to upgrade the clients to the latest and greatest, so we must branch, fix, test and release, on the version they currently have, yielding yet another version number.

The end result is that the version combo box is ludicrously long.  Lastly, for various reasons, we want to track three different version information :
the version in which the bug was found (version), the version in which we plan to fix (milestone) the bug and the version in which it has ultimately been fixed (open to suggestions).  here is my problem in fact... this can actually be multiple numbers where we did a retroactive fix for some of these customers (this happens VERY often).

This is where I need your collective wisdom :

**How do you keep track of these versions (found, planned and *multiple* fixed) in Bugzilla?**

**What are the best practices around linking versions and bug tracking ?**

---

## Answers

It seems that cloning the bug for each version is a good way to track, thus the target version is always tracked in the milestone as well as the fixed version, and the buggy version is always the native version.

Also to have each clone block the original bug make it a good way to trace the history back to the original submission.

Although I have accepted the answer I still welcome your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often, if we need to fix something in multiple released versions (generally branches in the source code repository), the bug will be cloned for each branch so that all the commits and release status can be tracked separately.  I think the only time we don't do this is when the change is not directly related to the codebase itself and cannot be fixed simply by updating our libraries.

As for version tracking in general, this has struck me as a reasonable way to do things, given that we generally only need to support 2-3 major versions (plus the trunk) at any time.  If you have multiple disjoint versions that need supporting, e.g. customer-specific deployments, then things are going to be harder to track.  (Arguably this is going to cause headaches in general and it would be better to unify things to a more central version theme).

Comment: Yes id does cause headaches, main reason why we want to move to bugzilla now later to subversion for the code.  Although we will be cleaning a lot of complexity enough remains to be problematic

Comment: Using a clone for each "active release branch" seems to be the closest thing to a standard way to handle this as exists. For tracking what is desired or needed to be done in the next release, it works well.

But it sucks anytime you want a unified view of the bug, information is spread through a multitude of clones. At best the clones are linked as dependencies of the "main" bug, and the summary helps with which branch they refer to, allowing you to hover over each one to see the branch and status.

Further, it dilutes searches, you now have n copies of the same bug.

Answer (score 3):

I use Bugzilla to keep track not only of bugs, but also of new features, enhancements, and vague ideas. For each planned and released version, I have a Tracking Bug (something that I saw on the original Mozilla bugzilla, and found to be useful).

So if you have a bug report, you enter the bug with the version number that it was reported. Create additional bugs (one for each version you plan to fix it in) which all depend on (block) the original bug and block the version-specific Tracking Bugs.

If all bugs blocking the original bug are closed/verified (whatever your QA implements), you can also close the original bug.

Comment: we do have an alternate means to track tasks but We do track requirements also in Bugzilla, mainly all that touches the source code will be tracked in bugzilla, thanks

Comment: I tried to read more about the "Tracking Bug" concept. Googling for this is a pain, since the term is so typical. Can you suggest a starting point for getting deeper into this technique (naming, keywording, etc.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know whether there is a formal definition, but have a look at Mozilla's bug tracker https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__open__&product=&content=meta&comments=0
Be aware that in the meantime Bugzilla evolved, and has additional fields such as Target Milestone to keep track of versions https://wiki.mozilla.org/BMO/UserGuide/BugFields

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a similar feature in TFS, and while doing some investigation, I found that there is an enhancement request to manage "sightings" in Bugzilla:
"Bug 55970 - (bz-branch) Bugzilla needs to deal better with branches (implement sightings)": 
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55970

There is also a proposed design:
https://bug55970.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=546912

For information, we are going to implement something similar in TFS 2010, with a "Bug Parent" or "Bug Master" to hold the information about the bug itself (repro steps, severity, technical info, impacted components...), that can have child of type "Bug Child" or "Sighting" that will hold the information specific to a given branch (target milestone, priority, specific information for that branch...).

Comment: [WONTFIX after 17 years](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55970#c90) ...maybe simply to complicated to deal with ;) BTW: thanks for picking out the design study  :)

Answer (score 2):

We are using jira and still have this problem.  I think it is a question of requirements and how are versions used rather than any one tool.

**Who uses versions and how do they use them?

How are versions related to milestones in a project plan?**

We use a 4 dectet version (major.minor.patch.buildNO).  buildNo is the SVN head revision # at time of build.  Each version is stored in JIRA and issues have an affects version and fixed-in version field that's a multi select.

After a short while we have many versions.  Jira does allow us to control the list in two ways
1. Archive versions (greyed out from pick list)
2. Merge versions (rolls several versions together into a new version - no undo)

We have used Archive, but have avoided Merge due to the lack of the undo.  So we still have a list of many many versions.

I'm sure you could probably accomplish a merge action in Bugzilla with some scripting and time, the question is: when is it OK to merge several older versions together?

If I have released, do I need to know that I have 17 builds between start and release?  Do I need to keep the knowledge of a bug being found in build 1, fixed in 2, found again in 7, fixed again 9?  Or is Found in release 1.0.0  fixed in release 1.0.1  good enough?

i'm going to ask a large question on this topic later on today, but I know the basic answer already:
- **Depends on how your team wants to track things.**

Implementation is fun, but it all comes down to requirements, goals and working back from user experience to solution.  Which is rough when people don't necessarily know how that want to use something that doesn't quite exist in the form they'd like to use.

Comment: I like the build numbering scheme.. makes it sooo much clearer than a synthetic number.  Thanks.  On the rest basically it is all a matter of what metric we wish to compile against the software version and what granularity we need it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom field (string) to list to version(s) (as V.M.P.B) where a bug has been fixed.
I have created also another custom field (string) to list to version(s) affected by a bug.
Doing that you are able to perform quick-search on specific version.